# Continue thread based on received data

Tags: c#, multithreading

Suppose I have 3 threads T1, T2, T3 waiting for data D1, D2, D3. The data is provided by another thread. How can I pause the threads and (A) let the one for the data at hand continue, or as another approach, how can I (B) let all three threads execute a single loop checking if they have data available and then stall again.

To make it a little bit more concrete, assume D2 will be available, then with solution (A) thread T2 should continue and with solution (B) all three would continue and verify if the data is for them, after the check stalling again if it wasn't for them.

I know I could solve this with a dictionary with a key for the data and an AutoResetEvent for each thread, but that doesn't seem very elegant... Is there a more elegant way?

Thanks!

Edwin.

Comment: Based on the data. You can use [BlockingCollection<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) for the "A" option.

Comment: Thanks. Looks promising. What would be a solution for .NET 3.5?

Comment: Move to .NET 4.6 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research, I found the solution myself for case (B), in IMHO [the most useful threading reference source](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx):

**How to Use Wait and Pulse**

Here's how to use Wait and Pulse:

Define a single field for use as the synchronization object, such as:

```
readonly object _locker = new object();
```

Define field(s) for use in your custom blocking condition(s). For example:

```
bool _go; or: int _semaphoreCount;
```

Whenever you want to block, include the following code:

```
lock (_locker)
  while ( <blocking-condition> )
    Monitor.Wait (_locker);
```

Whenever you change (or potentially change) a blocking condition, include this code:

```
lock (_locker)
{
  // Alter field(s) or data that might impact blocking condition(s)
  // ...
  Monitor.Pulse(_locker);  // or: Monitor.PulseAll (_locker);
}
```